# New to R, Try to add counter in the function

Tags: r, function

```
S<-function(n){
M<-4.132731
x<-double(n) 
i<-1
while(i<(n+1)){
C<-rcauchy(1) 
u<-runif(1)
temp<-(M^(-1))*(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-C^2/2)/1/(pi*(1+C^2))
if(u<-temp){
  x[i]<-C
  i<-i+1
}
}
return(c(x,counter))
}
```

I would like to have i=counter in my return. I need to know how many times I ran the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but I think his is it: if you mean that you're going to run this code many times, then you can do:

```
counter <- 0 # New

S<-function(n){
  M<-4.132731
  x<-double(n) 
  i<-1
  while(i<(n+1)){
    C<-rcauchy(1) 
    u<-runif(1)
    temp<-(M^(-1))*(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-C^2/2)/1/(pi*(1+C^2))
    if(u<-temp){
      x[i]<-C
      i<-i+1
    }
  }
  counter <- counter+Chan1 # New
  return(c(x,counter))
}
```

The `counter <- 1` goes before the function is called for the first time (or before that).

This code simply defines the function. If you want to repeat it arbitrarily many times, just to check it, you can do:

```
for (c in 1:100) {
  result <- S(12)
}

result
```

As you will see, this will give you only the *final* result, because it rewrites whatever came before. This is not good. Therefore, you may want to combine one result with the next. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to do it right now,

Comment: Thank you Erico.  I need to go through the while loop more than n times and I need to know how many times at the end I have gone through the while loop, This is to use for accept_Reject algorithm with a couch candidate.

Comment: Are you sure about `counter += 1`?

Comment: Oops. Forgot about that. @Joseph Wood is right, it's `counter <- counter+1`

Comment: I added as counter<-counter+1 and no error  But I need to return a list of x and counter which it doesn't do it.

Comment: It does, but it's a single vector. Check the last item. If you want, you can use `list()` instead of concatinate (`c()`)

Comment: Thank you Erico. I got 1. Now I think the question is how can I go through the loop more than n times? As it shows only one

Comment: I need to return (i) which is inside of the function

Answer (score 0):

Since `i` is initialized prior to the `while()` loop, it exists after the loop terminates. Therefore, to return it as the last object in the vector, simply add `i` in the return vector as follows:

```
set.seed(95014) # set seed to make example reproducible
S<-function(n){
     M<-4.132731
     x<-double(n) 
     i<-1
     while(i<(n+1)){
          C<-rcauchy(1) 
          u<-runif(1)
          temp<-(M^(-1))*(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-C^2/2)/1/(pi*(1+C^2))
          if(u<-temp){
               x[i]<-C
               i<-i+1
          }
     }
     return(c(x,i))
}

S(1)
S(2)
S(3)
```

...and the output demonstrating that `i` is always the input to `S()` plus 1:

```
> S(1)
[1] -0.1973752  2.0000000
> S(2)
[1] 0.7706051 1.5905587 3.0000000
> S(3)
[1]  5.7787076  0.4051221 -0.5227564  4.0000000
```

To return the exact number of times that the loop has been executed, we can simply subtract 1 from the value of `i` before returning it.

```
return(c(x,i-1))
```

...and the output:

```
> S(1)
[1] -0.1973752  1.0000000
> S(2)
[1] 0.7706051 1.5905587 2.0000000
> S(3)
[1]  5.7787076  0.4051221 -0.5227564  3.0000000
```

We can replace the `while()` loop with `lapply()` to reduce the number of counters and intermediate variables.

```
set.seed(95014)
S<-function(n){
     M<-4.132731
     x <- unlist(lapply(1:n,function(x){
          C<-rcauchy(1) 
          u<-runif(1)
          temp <- (M^(-1))*(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-C^2/2)/1/(pi*(1+C^2))
          if(u<-temp){
               return(C)
          }              
     }))
     return(c(x,n))
}
S(1)
S(2)
S(3)
```

...and the output, which matches the results from the original function:

```
> S(1)
[1] -0.1973752  1.0000000
> S(2)
[1] 0.7706051 1.5905587 2.0000000
> S(3)
[1]  5.7787076  0.4051221 -0.5227564  3.0000000
```

**WARNING:** potential defect in the code in the question that must be resolved by the person who asked it:

```
if(u<-temp) # this will always return TRUE
```